# post request with form-data from angular to spring

Tags: angular, spring, spring-mvc, angular7, angular-http

i am trying to send a post request to my spring rest api using angular and its http library.

currently in post-man (sucessfully) i am sending the data in this way:

1. The format is form-data
2. The key is reqData(mandatory)
3. The Value is json(mandatory)

[image: post-man,request]

how to send the data in the same way via angular?

currently, this is how my data looks like:

```
onSignIn(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;

    const reqData = {
      'app_uname': email,
      'app_pass': password
    };
}
```

adding more about my backend code:

my rest api looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)

@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(@RequestParam(value = "reqData") String reqData,HttpServletRequest request)
```

so i should be sending a key and value ( i am not aware which data structure in typescript,but in java it is MultiValueMap) where the key is reqData and the value should be json in string or json object.

**how to make my reqData json in angular to MultiValueMap format?**

i have tried both formData and Map also:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('reqData', JSON.stringify(reqData));

const map = new Map();
    map.set('reqData', reqData);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0):

To send data to server using formdata using can do this like this

```
const email = form.value.email;
const password = form.value.password;

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append("email ", email);
formData.append("password ", password);

// then http post to server
```

Edit

if you want to submit the data as json you need to do like this

```
const email = form.value.email;
const password = form.value.password;

const reqData = {
  'app_uname': email,
  'app_pass': password
};

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append("reqData", JSON.stringify(reqData));

// then http post to server and in the server you need to parse the json string
```

Hope it solve your problem. Please let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: The key should be reqData and the value should be JSON of email and password.your answer doesn't help.

Comment: The request payload is empty. meaning the data is null.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method to post as below:

```
var model = {email: youremail, password: yourpassword};
post(url: string, model: any): Observable <any> {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('app_uname', model.email); 
    formData.append('app_pass', model.password); 
    return this._http.post(url, formData)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response;
        }).catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

Comment: please try to see what kind of data i want,key should be reqData and value should be json.

Comment: whatever key you want to send with json object then try to convert by json.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done to send request to my backend.

i created the required json,then i created a request parameter string

```
const reqData = 'reqData=' + jsonDataInString;
```

which sent a success request.