# angular 8 post rest service not working with spring boot - giving null in HttpServletRequest

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, angular8

I am working on a angular application. In that I have to send data to backend post api call . I am using 'formdata' to send file. 
But when I am checking java side in spring boot controller HttpServletRequest is don't have the data we send from angular (when I read userId from request I got null)

this below is my angular code

```
const formData = new FormData();
for(let j=0;j<this.fileLists.length; j++)
{
  formData.append("files",<File>this.fileLists[j]);
}
formData.append('userId','magic123');
this.homeService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe(data => {
  console.log("result is ", data)
})


uploadFiles(formdata){
return this.http.post("upload url",formdata);
}
```

and the below is my java code

```
java

@CrossOrigin(origins = ("http://localhost:4200"))
@PostMapping(value = "/upload" )
public ResponseEntity<CdccUploadResponseVO> uploadJSON(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, 
HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
throws CALValidationException
{
  System.out.println("Controller================================get is"+httpRequest.getParameter("userId"));
```

I am  getting null in httpRequest.getParameter("userId")

edit 1:when I tried in postman , API is working only when we are sending data as multipart form. otherwise the same the error like angular. So how can I send send Multipart form from angular instead of Formdata.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo in the Angular code, it should be with lowercase `f`:

`return this.http.post("upload url", formData);`

Also, `"upload url"` should match the url of Spring Boot `@PostMapping` but presumably you have just edited that out. I hope this helps.

Comment: lowercase only I am using.. it was a typo. 'upload url' is correct it is reaching system.out.println

Comment: In that case your code looks good to me. I wonder if you work with authorization headers, and if so, whether these are correctly set up server-side? You can also try adding `@RequestParam String userId` in the method, and see if Spring gives you a meaningful error.

Comment: server side call is tested via postman. It is working. If we open HttpServletRequest, where would we can see the data ?  I tried  @RequestParam String userId and got 401 error. because userId was null

Comment: 401 is an `unauthorized` error, implying there is an authorization issue. Try switching off any authorization on the server, if you can, to see if this was the issue.

Comment: when I tried in postman , API is working only when we are sending data as multipart form. otherwise the same the error like angular. So how can I send send Multipart form from angular instead of Formdata.

Comment: Using `FormData` in Angular, and using `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` in Spring Boot is a good approach. And a `401` error is an `unauthorized` error, suggesting that the problem is with authorization. I don't think I have anything more to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

ref-: [post request with form-data from angular to spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842920/post-request-with-form-data-from-angular-to-spring)